# Attach current location in Gmail

Tags: windows, gmail, geo-location

I am looking for a Windows program or Google Chrome extension that can attach  my [current location](http://ctrlq.org/maps/where/) as an image to an email I am writing in the Gmail web interface. (as one can do in [Google Hangouts](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/6142837?hl=en):

[image]

)

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.